# chrome.tabs.query event not triggering

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to work with chrome extensions lately and right now I'm just trying to get familiar with the chrome apis.

Specifically, I'm testing out chrome.tabs.query to create an alert with the URL of the currently active tab, but the event doesn't trigger. Here is the code for my background.js file.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    var activeTabUrl = activeTab.url;
    alert(activeTabUrl);
});
```

And here is my manifest.json. I'm pretty sure all the permissions are correct.

```
{

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Time Tracker",
    "description": "Track how much time spent on ...",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": ["history", "bookmarks", "activeTab", "tabs"],
    "background":{
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://*.www.youtube.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "/images/clock.png"
    }
}
```

I've also tried out other chrome apis such as chrome.history.onVisited to try and add an eventListener but nothing seems to be working.

I've added a link to the full repo here.
https://github.com/ismail-ahmed0149/Time-Tracker

Update #1 June 2. 2021 (Response to most recent comment)

Here is my most recent code my background script.

```
function handleUpdated(tabId, changeInfo, tabInfo) {
  console.log("Updated tab: " + tabId);
  console.log("Changed attributes: ");
  console.log(changeInfo);
  console.log("New tab Info: ");
  console.log(tabInfo);
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(handleUpdated);


chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){

    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    var activeTabUrl = activeTab.url;
    alert(activeTabUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find docs for chrome.tabs events here:
[LINK](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onActivated)

(scroll down till the end)

You have to add a "onUpdated" event in your background script.

Comment: I added the first code snippet under the examples section from here at the top of my background script just to test it out but I'm not seeing anything in the console. (scroll to the bottom) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated I honestly don't know if there's something wrong with my chrome.

Comment: Let's focus on the alert you want to see when the page url changes and forget the content script!
Can you please post the background in its entirety?

Comment: I added an update at the bottom of my post giving my background.js file in its entirety as of rn. I appreciate the help :)

Comment: I've commented the "content_scripts" section in manifest.json and convert alert(activeTabUrl) in console.log(activeTabUrl). Alert cannot be used anymore in MV3 background scripts (aka extension service worker). After this few mods everything works fine. I tryed to change url in a tab and onUpdate event triggers fine.